# How to return a value from another workbook that changes location every day

Tags: vba, excel

Hello again stackoverflow. My question today is on returning a value from a cell on another sheet with few constants. I have a series of columns that take an unalterable input and convert it into useful data with a few formulas and macros. The end result, is something akin to;

```
( A )                            
Cage
10
ct
Cage
5
ct
Bin
3
CT
Bin
4
CT
CT
Bin
11
CT
```

What I would like to do is find "Bin", in A1:A16 then return the value directly under it to a cell on sheet2. Then, I need to count how many "ct's" are present under that "Bin", and return the value to a cell adjacent to the total on sheet2 for an output something like;

```
Bin1 3 1   Bin2 4 2   Bin3 11 1
```

The location of the information will change every day, but it will stay in the same row. The order will always be constant, for instance, the 3 will correspond with the first Bin, the 4 with the second, and the 11 with the third, though there may well be more or less each day.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Since the ordering is constant, the easiest solution might be to create a VBA routine which converts the 1D array into a proper table on another sheet.  Do you know how to get started doing that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm mediocre with Excel, and my experience with VBA is nearly non-existent. I can usually edit a piece of code to do what I want, but to write it myself, I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that under a "Bin" the value you requested is always present, and that you want to write each "Bin X Y" in cells A1, A2, A3, ... in a second sheet which you haven't already opened (so this will basically open a new one for you):

```
Sub Bin_count()

Dim i As Byte, j As Byte, CTs As Byte
Dim ThisPage As Worksheet, TargetPage As Worksheet
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Set ThisPage = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add   ' or you can address an existing file with workbooks.open(filename)
Set TargetPage = NewBook.Worksheets(1) ' you can also decide the sheet where you want to write your values (here by default is the first excel's "tab")

j = 1 ' Results cells scanner

For i = 1 To 17

    If ThisPage.Cells(i, 1).Text = "Bin" Then                                     ' if "Bin is found...

        ThisPage.Activate
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Activate

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)                                              ' ...scan all cells below...
            If ActiveCell.Text = "CT" Then CTs = CTs + 1                          '...to find all CTs and store their number in a variable...
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Loop

        TargetPage.Cells(1, j) = "Bin " & ThisPage.Cells(i + 1, 1) & " " & CTs '... at the end and write Bin + number under it + number of CTs found
        j = j + 1  ' should you need to write in column instead of row, simply write targetpage.cells(j,1) instead of the previous statement

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can do it without "activates", but in my opinion, since you're unexperienced, you may find a debugging easier with them... Just in case ;)

Comment: I appreciate this Noldor, looks a lot closer than I was getting, if you need more information please look at my comment to the response below, I linked the spreadsheet I'm having the problem with. Thanks again

Comment: Hmmm I didn't find any link... Can you tell me if you have any error with the procedure I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `Do...Loop` with the `Range.Find` method, since your information will change from day to day. As an example that doesn't require sorting, and that stays flexible with changing data:

```
Dim bin_count As Integer 'bin count
bin_count = 1
Dim sheet2_plcmnt As Integer 'sheet 2 placeholder
sheet2_plcmnt = 1

Dim cur_row As Long 'current row
Dim nxt_row As Long 'next row
Dim loop_tst As Integer 'loop test

'---prime do...loop---
cur_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find("Bin").Row
nxt_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") _
  .FindNext(Cells(cur_row, 1)).Row
loop_tst = 0
'delete previous data in Sheet2, row 1
Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Delete
'use .activate so CountIf works properly in loop below
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'---run loop through all cells in column A---
'= 0 have not reached end; = 1 reached end but need to run
'one more time; = 2 exit loop
Do While loop_tst < 2
  'put in values...
  'bin # (contiguous, starting at 1)
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, sheet2_plcmnt).Value = _
    "Bin" & bin_count
  '# after bin
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, sheet2_plcmnt + 1).Value = _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(cur_row + 1, 1).Value
  '# of CTs after bin
  If loop_tst < 1 Then
    'if haven't reached end, check between cur_row and nxt_row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, sheet2_plcmnt + 2).Value = _
      WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(cur_row, 1), _
      Cells(nxt_row, 1)), "CT")
  Else
    'if have reached end, check between cur_row and
    'last row in column A
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, sheet2_plcmnt + 2).Value = _
      WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(cur_row, 1), _
      Range("A1").End(xlDown)), "CT")
  End If
  '...change counters as needed
  bin_count = bin_count + 1
  sheet2_plcmnt = sheet2_plcmnt + 3
  cur_row = nxt_row
  'set next row
  nxt_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") _
    .FindNext(Cells(cur_row, 1)).Row
  'adjust to determine loop behavior
  If loop_tst = 1 Then loop_tst = 2
  If cur_row > nxt_row Then loop_tst = 1
Loop
```

If you use this, please note it will delete previous data from Sheet2 row 1 so no remnants are left from previous counts.
The `Worksheet.Activate` method is used once to make sure the `CountIf` function works correctly. If someone knows a way to avoid this, the code could be modified to work without any `Select` or `Activate`.

Comment: Actually, if you wanted to optimize even more, sheet2_plcmnt could be replaced with `(1/3*bin_count)+(2/3)`.